# Returning Quantity of Current Cart Entry using Django View

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following view where I want to return the quantity of the current cart entry.

```
def test_view(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    my_carts_current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=cart_obj)
    product_quantity = request.POST.get('product_quantity')
    return render(request, 'carts/test.html', {'my_cart': cart_obj, 'my_carts_current_entries': my_carts_current_entries})
```

How would I reference the current entry quantity, e.g. if there is an entry in the database called 23x Chicken Nuggets I want it to return the quantity.

On the template if I return:

```
{{ my_carts_current_entries }}
```

it will return all the current entries but without the quantity.

For clarity I have included an extract of my models.py from the said application:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart:{} User:{} Items:{} Total:£{}".format(self.id, self.user, self.count, self.total)

class Entry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Comment: You need quantities of Entry instances or total quantities of Entry instances. Total or per object?

Comment: I need it per object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in template:

```
{% for cart in  my_carts_current_entries %}
     {{ cart.product }} - {{ cart.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```